# Display upload progress, using Google Cloud Storage API on ASP .NET Webforms

Tags: webforms, google-cloud-storage

I'm developing an ASP .NET C# Webforms Application and I want it to be able to upload jpg images to a specified Google Bucket.

I'm able to upload the files without any issue, but I would like to be able to monitor (and display a progress bar) that would inform the User how much has already been uploaded (or how much is missing to complete)

My page contains an input tag (to select the file from filesystem) and a button that performs the upload.

Here's my code Onclick handler:

```
 protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     // TODO: Validate file type (extension / Mime type, etc)

     // All auth settings wer removed for simplicity
     
     // Here, I'm declaring the handler that will take care of upload progress
     IProgress<IUploadProgress> progress = new Progress<IUploadProgress>(OnUploadProgress);
     

     // Generate new image filename (guid based)
     string imageFilenameGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

     var googleStorageClient = StorageClient.Create(googleCloudCredentials);
     
     // Upload options (chunck sizes)
     //UploadObjectOptions uplOptions = new UploadObjectOptions();
     //uplOptions.ChunkSize = 262144;

     // Here's where the upload is done. The upload occurs successfully
     Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object uploadedObject = googleStorageClient.UploadObject(strGoogleCloudBucketName, string.Format("{0}.jpg", imageFilenameGuid), "image/jpeg", oFile.PostedFile.InputStream, null , progress);     
 }
```

The HTML look pretty much like this:

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="oFile" runat="server" Width="400px" />

<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" Text="Upload" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpload_Click"></asp:Button>
```

Finally the handler code:

```
// Called when progress updates
protected void OnUploadProgress(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress)
{
    switch (progress.Status)
    {
        case Google.Apis.Upload.UploadStatus.Starting:
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Starting");
                //ProgressBar.Minimum = 0;
                //ProgressBar.Value = 0;

                break;
            }
            
        case Google.Apis.Upload.UploadStatus.Completed:
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Completed");
                //ProgressBar.Value = ProgressBar.Maximum;
                //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Upload completed");

                break;
            }
            
        case Google.Apis.Upload.UploadStatus.Uploading:
            {
                litDebug.Text = DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString();
                Debug.WriteLine("Uploading");
                //UpdateProgressBar(progress.BytesSent);

                break;
            }
            
        case Google.Apis.Upload.UploadStatus.Failed:
            Debug.WriteLine("Failed");
            //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Upload failed"
            //                              + Environment.NewLine
            //                              + progress.Exception);
            break;
    }
}
```

The problem is: While the upload is is progress, there's no messages on the "Immediate Window". But, AFTER the upload is complete, I see all the log messages AT ONCE.

Something like:

Starting
Uploading
Uploading
Uploading
Uploading
Uploading
Uploading
Uploading
Completed

Could someone spot what am I'm  doing wrong (or needs to be changed) in order to dispatch this messages once they occur?

Thank you in advance (and forgive me as I may not have formatted the code correctly).